# Regex in discord.py purge check?

Tags: python, discord, pycord, purge

Is it possible to implement a regex check in the `check` argument of `discord.TextChannel.purge`?

I believe that I have to use lambda or something, but I'm really not sure. Any example would be appreciated!

I'm using the latest version of both `pycord` and `re`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lambda` can be used. You have to define a method to check if the message matches the Regex.

```
def matches(message, regex):
    if re.match(regex, message): return True
    return False


#Either get your regex from the command/message content or just set it to a variable.
arg = "\d+" #arbitrary
await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10, check=lambda message, regex=arg: matches(message, regex))
```

Edit: Fixed code. Was wrong. Now right.